# the full page doesn't appear on local host in odoo

Tags: localhost, odoo

This is the output when I run the code on pycharm
[code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frOsE.png)

But this is what appears on the browser on localhost8069 
[on local host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgWQm.png)

I want the full page 
thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the contents of your `odoo-server.conf`. It is probably in `/etc/odoo-server.conf`

Comment: I have editted the post with hyper link

Comment: this is the config. 
in script parameters:
-w odoo -r odoo --addons-path=C:\code\erp\odoo\openerp\addons,C:\code\erp\custemized_modules -u Training